# Delete linespacing in multiline string Python

Tags: python, formatting, line-breaks

I have a string which looks like this when I print it:

```
RT @HHRoadGuy: It's that time again! Time to tune in for the latest #fortheloveofmusic episode. Catch it now on @CMT!

http://t.co/VatlhGq9â€¦
```

I tried to get rid of the linespacing with:

```
tweet = tweet.rstrip('\r\n')
```

But it does not work. Probably as the linespacing is inbetween. Also the replace function could not help. What can I do here?

Comment: *the replace function could not help* - In what way? What did you attempt?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Really stupid question. I just had a small error in my code. Sorry. tweet = tweet.replace('\n','')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tweet = tweet.replace('\n','')
```

Is the answer. I just had a tiny error in my code and after trying all these different methods and things I got blind. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the line delimeters are indeed '\r\n' and not just '\n'?
Because `replace()` should work just fine:

```
>>> s = 'hello\r\n\r\nhi'
>>> print(s)
hello

hi
>>> s2 = s.replace('\r\n\r\n', '\r\n')
>>> print(s2)
hello
hi
```

Indeed, the `rstrip()` will not work, since that function only strips on the right (end) of the string.

Answer (score 1):

There are many line break characters:
`\n` `\n\r` `\r` depending on the text input.

Look http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline, depending on your input text and replace that character

Answer (score 1):

The following should work in most cases to get rid of all line breaks, regardless of how they're represented:

```
lines = tweet.splitlines()
tweet = " ".join(lines)
```

Or, to avoid double spacing (and adopting P.M.'s concept):

```
tweet = " ".join([line for line in lines if len(line)])
```

If you wanted to only get rid of blank lines but preserve line breaks:

```
tweet = "\n".join([line for line in lines if len(line)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
>>> '\n'.join([line for line in your_text.splitlines() if line.strip()])
```

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines for more informations on how it handles line breaks.